# Fundamental Solution / Greens function for Kramers / Langevin equation nowhere to be found

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, greens-function, statistical-mechanics, fundamental-solution

I am looking for a reference to the fundamental solution\Greens function  of the two dimensional Kramers PDE

$$\partial_t \rho(t,x,v) = -v\frac{\partial}{dx}\rho(t,x,v)+\gamma\frac{\partial}{\partial v}(v\rho(t,x,v)) +\frac{\partial^2}{dv^2}\rho(t,x,v) $$

with $x,v\in\mathbb{R}$ and some constant $\gamma>0$. I have really looked hard and am confused why this is not readily available on the net. I found it in this book but Elements of 'Nonequilibrium Statistical Mechanics' by V. Balakrishnan but there are typos in this work. Does anyone have a correct reference?

Comment: What is the expression in the book? How was it derived?

Comment: @Sal its quite long and has the notation of the book, moreover I have noticed it must be wrong/have a typo. Either way this is such a famous equation why cant I easily find the fundamental solution?

Comment: Do you mean equation 13.16?

Comment: 12.26 and 12.27, are the solution Im looking for but these are not even equal ! Moreover, I want the marginals and im pretty sure 12.32 and 12.33 might have some typos, I want another source to double check.